# What is the "reconciliation" mentioned in 2 Corinthians 5:20?

Tags: word-study, new-testament, authorial-intent, pauline-epistles, 2-corinthians

What is the **reconciliation** mentioned in

> [2 Corinthians 5:20](https://biblehub.com/2_corinthians/5-20.htm) Therefore we are ambassadors for Christ, as
>   though God were making His appeal through us. We implore you on behalf
>   of Christ: Be **reconciled** to God.

?

Since Paul is writing believers who are already reconciled to God by the death of Jesus [Romans 5:10](https://biblehub.com/romans/5-10.htm)[2](https://biblehub.com/romans/5-10.htm) , why is he again asking them to be reconciled to God?

Answer (score 1):

18 And all things are of God, who hath reconciled us to himself by Jesus Christ, and hath given to us the ministry of reconciliation;

19 To wit, that God was in Christ, reconciling the world unto himself, not imputing their trespasses unto them; and hath committed unto us the word of reconciliation.

20 Now then we are ambassadors for Christ, as though God did beseech you by us: we pray you in Christ's stead, be ye reconciled to God.

Reconciliation here presented is concerning salvation. Verse 18 makes this clear. Verse 18 is past tense, "hath reconciled". And "has given us the ministry of reconciliation". The simple point is this is the Christians purpose of being still here on this earth, to be used as ambassadors or representatives of Christ's mercy and forgivrnessness through faith in Him. Paul always preached the Gospel even to believers. Remember, just because they were Apostles doesn't mean they knew who the elect were. Even today we preach reconciliation to professing christians, because only God "knows those who are His"

Comment: Reconciled from sin unto holiness through the sacrifice of Christ Jesus which allows us access unto God through his sacrifice on the cross which is well pleasing unto God and an acceptable sacrifice for our sins. Once repentance, baptism and the spirit of God come into someone who believes the gospel, God begins to direct through His word and Spirit indwelling in us to the sanctification and salvation of our souls.

Answer (score -1):

2 Corinthians 5:20

"We are therefore Christ’s ambassadors, as though God were making his appeal through us. We implore you on Christ’s behalf: Be reconciled to God"

Paul the Apostle was correcting the assembly of whom were becoming disobedient, thus He was reminding them of God's grace and salvation through Christ, admonishing them to repent of there behavior.

2 Corinthians 6-7 further reveals as to why he hasked them to reconcile/come back to God.

Comment: I believe it does, the Corinthian church was sinning and Paul reminded them of God's grace through Christ, admonishing them to return back to God through Repentance thus paul was asking them to change/reconcile toward God.such passages need to be interpreted within the immediate and surrounding context. The chapters 6-7 clarify why He told the members of that congregation to reconcile toward God.